# How do I get rid of a random new line in a text file using Python?

Tags: python, parsing

I currently a bunch of variations of this in a text file:

```
2   /vol/vol0/home  /vol/vol0/home  CifsPerm: 0, CifsType: 0, Remark: 
Up-level share detected.    0   NFS /vol/vol0/home  ntap
```

But need it to be all in one line, like this:

```
2   /vol/vol0/home  /vol/vol0/home  CifsPerm: 0, CifsType: 0, Remark: Up-level share detected.  0   NFS /vol/vol0/home  ntap
```

For some reason all of the sudden new lines start with 'Up-level'. How would I go about doing this? I'm very new to Python and would be grateful for any ideas for how I may solve this.

My code (which is for some reason is throwing everything into the same line):

```
def bad_line_2(line): 
    if "Up-level" in line:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def inventory_append(in_file_2, out_fixed_inv): 
    try:
        in_fp_2 = open(in_file_2, "r")

    except IOError as e:
        print("error opening {} for reading: {}".format(in_file_2, str(e)))

    else:
        try:
            out_inv = open(out_fixed_inv, "w")

        except IOError as e:
            print("error opening {} for writing: {}".format(out_fixed_inv, str(e)))
        else:
            with open(in_file_2) as f:
                out = integer.join(line.rstrip('\n') for line in f
                out_inv.write(out)

def main():
    in_file_2 = "Inventory 2017-12-21.txt"
    out_fixed_inv = "fixed_inv.txt" 
    inventory_append(in_file_2, out_fixed_inv)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Text file sample:

```
2   usfptotnap101a  C$  \vol\vol0   232 8   0   4474560 Share   3   0   CifsPerm: 0, CifsType: 2147483648, Remark: Remote Administration    0   CIFS & NFS  /vol/vol0   ntap
2   usfptotnap101a  ETC$    \vol\vol0\etc   508 1   0   4474561 Share   1   1   CifsPerm: 0, CifsType: 2147483648, Remark: Remote Administration
Up-level share detected.    0   CIFS    NULL    ntap
2   usfptotnap101a  Varonis$    \vol\it_tot101a_181099\Varonis  7159534 44  4   4474551 Share   1   1   CifsPerm: 0, CifsType: 0, Remark: 
Up-level share detected.    0   CIFS    NULL    ntap
2   usfptotnap101a  smtest  \vol\smtest\smtree  7715986 1   0   4474559 Share   1   0   CifsPerm: 0, CifsType: 0, Remark:   0   CIFS    NULL    ntap
```

Comment: Please include the code that you are using to generate the text file in your post so that we can help you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, I have updated my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said its variations of given example, here is something that probably can help you:

```
results = []

with open(YOUR_FILE, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    results = ['%s%s\n' % (i.strip(), j.strip()) for i, j in zip(lines[::2], lines[1::2])]

with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(results)
```

Now, what this does? It makes pairs of 1st and 2nd line, 3nd and 4th, and so on, and then concatenates them. This is good solution if file you have is not very big in size. If it is, there are other solutions. Reason why it is not good solution for huge files is because it reads all lines all at once with `readlines`.

### Edit 1.

Code above appears to be not suitable since lines aren't split in assumed pattern.

By the example of your file and functions that you use, here is how updated version should look like:

```
def read_lines(file_handle):
    """
    :param file file_handle:
    :return: List of parsed lines
    :rtype list[str]
    """
    results = [] # correctly parsed lines
    buffer = ""
    for line in file_handle:
        if not line.startswith('Up-level'):
            if buffer:
                # you have loaded previous line in buffer
                # and current line doesn't start with 'Up-level'
                # this means it's just another regular line and
                # you have to 'flush' the buffer in results
                results.append(buffer + '\n')
            # whether buffer was filled and you just flushed it
            # or it was empty, you load new line in it.
            buffer = line.strip()
        else:
            # when line starts with 'Up-level' you add it to
            # previously parsed one which should be in buffer
            # when next line is parsed this ends up in results
            buffer += line.strip()
    else:
        # last line, that is also in buffer, is appended to results too
        results.append(line)

    return results

def inventory_append(in_file_2, out_fixed_inv):
    try:
        in_fp_2 = open(in_file_2, "r")

    except IOError as e:
        print("error opening {} for reading: {}".format(in_file_2, str(e)))

    else:
        try:
            out_inv = open(out_fixed_inv, "w")

        except IOError as e:
            print("error opening {} for writing: {}".format(out_fixed_inv, str(e)))
        else:
            with open(in_file_2) as f:
                lines = read_lines(f)
                out_inv.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Great idea! However, the lines have errors randomly in the file, there is no order to them so unfortunately this didn't work. I appreciate it though!

Comment: Okay then. Without having a sample of all variations there is no universal solution. There must be some pattern in file content that can help you. Can you provide some sample of file contents?

Comment: I wish there were a pattern lol. The error lines are random. I just edited the question to include a sample! I want to be able to have the code be like "if line starts with "Up-level", then append this line to previous.

Comment: I have updated the answer with what might solve your issue.

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you so much! With hard work, I hope to be as quick and helpful as you one day.

Comment: Would appreciate if you could comment on the lines, I'm having difficulty understanding the code and would love to be able to replicate it on my own!